# bind function parameter to specific register

Tags: gcc, function-calls

Can I make a **gcc** to place the specific function (**C** or **C++**) parameter to the specific register? I want to define the function prototype to use by some naked code, that exploits this register, say, as the base. I mean something like [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Reg-Vars.html), but towards a function parameter.

Comment: You could use [inline assembly](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) for that.

Comment: but I dont want to use any wrappers to call that functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't request that a particular function parameter be placed in a given register. This is because the way function parameters are passed to a function is defined by the ABI for your architecture. For example, on x86-64, the first 6 (integral) parameters are passed in the registers `%rdi`, `%rsi`, `%rdx`, `%rcx`, `%r8`, and `%r9`.

What you can do is use [local register vars](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Reg-Vars.html), as you indicated, to assign a particular local variable to a register, and then copy the parameter into that local variable. This should cause the parameter to be copied into that register.

That said, why do you even want this?